# Cascades NavigationPane: connect to an object signal into another qml file

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-cascades

I've created a blackberry application using the wizard with `NavigationPane` template, and added some components on the DetailsPage.qml (like a `Button` and a `TextField`).

I want to connect a slot function on the button in DetailsPage.qml, that when clicked read the text into the `TextArea` on the same page.

My problem is that when the application is launched, the qml that is loaded is main.qml. 
If i try to get reference to an object on DetailsPage.qml `findChild` return 0x0, because it cannot find it. 
The main.qml file is:

```
// Navigation pane project template
import bb.cascades 1.0

NavigationPane {
    id: navigationPane
    Page {
        // page with a picture thumbnail
        Container {
            background: Color.Black
            layout: DockLayout {
            }
            Button {                
                horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                text: qsTr("New todo")
                imageSource: "asset:///images/picture1thumb.png"
                onClicked: {
                    // show detail page when the button is clicked
                    var page = getSecondPage();
                    console.debug("pushing detail " + page)
                    navigationPane.push(page);
                }
                property Page secondPage
                function getSecondPage() {
                    if (! secondPage) {
                        secondPage = secondPageDefinition.createObject();
                    }
                    return secondPage;
                }
                attachedObjects: [
                    ComponentDefinition {
                        id: secondPageDefinition
                        objectName: "secondPageDefinition"
                        source: "DetailsPage.qml"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    onCreationCompleted: {
        // this slot is called when declarative scene is created
        // write post creation initialization here
        console.log("NavigationPane - onCreationCompleted()");

        // enable layout to adapt to the device rotation
        // don't forget to enable screen rotation in bar-bescriptor.xml (Application->Orientation->Auto-orient)
        OrientationSupport.supportedDisplayOrientation = SupportedDisplayOrientation.All;
    }
}
```

The detailsPage.qml file is:

```
// Navigation pane project template
import bb.cascades 1.0

Page {
    // page with a picture detail
    id: pgDetail
    objectName: "pgDetail"
    actions: [
        // create navigation panel actions here
        ActionItem {
            title: qsTr("Break")
            onTriggered: {
                imgView.imageSource = "asset:///images/picture1br.png"
            }
        }
    ]
    paneProperties: NavigationPaneProperties {
        backButton: ActionItem {
            onTriggered: {
                // define what happens when back button is pressed here
                // in this case is closed the detail page
                navigationPane.pop()
            }
        }
    }
    Container {
        background: Color.Black
        Label {
            text: qsTr("Page 2")
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            textStyle {
                base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.TitleText
                color: Color.Yellow
            }
        }
        ImageView {
            id: imgView
            imageSource: "asset:///images/picture1.png"
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
        }
        Label {
            text: qsTr("Picture description")
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
        }
        TextArea {
            objectName: "noteText"
        }
        Button {
            objectName: "insertBtn"
            text: qsTr("Insert Note")
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to connect the button using the signal `pushTransactionEnded`, but it has two problems:

1. The connect method is called every time i change screen (and i want to connect the slot only on startup).
2. When i the button is clicked, i have the same problem, i have no reference to the currentPage (but maybe if i save the root pane in that case, using the top() method, i can obtain access to the current Page)

So basically my questions are: 
When i must connect my slot to a signal? 
How i do that, if the objects are on a different qml file?

I want to handle the clicked event on C++ not directly in qml File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register C++ object containing your slot with qml using setContextProperty and call that slot directly from DetailsPage.qml

```
    ...
    Button {

        objectName: "insertBtn"
        text: qsTr("Insert Note")
        onClicked:{
             cppObject.mySlot()
        }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create alias as QT

```
Button {
    id:first_button
    text: "original text"
    onCreationComplete{
         Qt.first_qml_fitst_button = first_button
    }            
 }
```

and on second form you can have

```
Button {
    id:second_button
    onClicked:{
         Qt.first_qml_fitst_button.text = "i change text"
    }
 }
```